# Struct in netbeans

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, struct

I have a problem concerning the usage of struct I have in my table in Microsoft SQL Server. I am working in NetBeans 8.0 and I don't know how to connect the two of them. In Microsoft Visual it is done by creating a class that has the structure same as struct in Microsoft Visual and all the corresponding methods, then connecting the two of them, but I don't know how to do the same thing in NetBeans, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what "In Microsoft Visual it is done by creating a class that has the structure same as struct in Microsoft Visual" means?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in Microsoft Visual I am supposed to create a struct which is serializable and has the attributes struct is supposed to have in a table in MSSQL.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear, i use EntityFramework a lot oder even good old DataSet, but i never had to code a struct? What does "Microsoft Visual" mean? Visual Studio? VisualBasic? Can you give some context?

Comment: It is for a college project, I have a user defined type which is struct, it is a table attribute consisting of several attributes. In Microsoft Visual Studio, in C#, it is implemented throught struct. I need to do the same thing in NetBeans. Is there any way to do that?